# Automate CloudFoundry Deployment with python

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud Foundry. I want to automate the application deployment and service binding in Cloud Foundry with Python.

For deploying an application in Cloud Foundry we will use the commands (Cloud Foundry CLI) like:

```
cf push redis-sample-app
cf create-service redis shared-vm service-example-redis
cf bind-service redis-sample-app service-example-redis
cf restage redis-sample-app
```

Now I don't want to use the CLI for that, I just want to write a Python/Ruby/(any language) script which will do all the things.

I have tried google and ended up with Python `cloudfoundry` module, but it's not clear to go on. Is there any API for my task, like `boto` for accessing EC2. I have tried following code in Python:

```
from cloudfoundrty import CloudFoundryInterface
cf=CloudFoundryInterface(target="api.end.point",username="myusername",password="mypwd")
cf.login()
```

It's showing the error:

```
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 398, in full_url
    raise MissingSchema("Invalid URL %r: No schema supplied" % url)
MissingSchema: Invalid URL    u'users/kishorekumarnetala%40gmail.com/tokens': No schema supplied`
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a quick thing, what is the actual API endpoint of your Cloud Foundry deployment?  If you're using the `cf` CLI, what did you put when you did `cf api API_ENDPOINT`? You can run `cf target` to see what the current API endpoint is set to.  It should have a scheme like `http` or `https`.  If you're actually putting `api.end.point` in your Python code, that's why you're getting the error message you're seeing.

As for your general question about automating Cloud Foundry interactions, you have a few options:

1. Write a shell script that directly drives the `cf` CLI
2. Write a module in a higher-level language like Ruby or Python that simply wraps calls to the CLI
3. Write a module in a higher-level language that wraps calls to the restful API.

Here's a breakdown of those options:

1. If your list of languages (Ruby/Python/any language) included things like `bash` or pure `sh`, then you can easily use that to have "code" that automates interacting with Cloud Foundry.  The CLI is designed to be scriptable, and not require human interaction.  This is the most common approach, since the CLI is designed for this use case.
2. If you want to drive interactions via a different language (e.g. maybe because this is part of a larger project that's already in a different language), you can certainly do that.  The full suite of highest level system tests for Cloud Foundry does this in Golang.  If you're familiar with navigating Golang projects, you can look at:

   - the [package](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-test-helpers) that drives the CLI
   - the [test suites](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-acceptance-tests) that use that package
3. You can also build a wrapper around the [RESTful HTTP API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/226/). There are also several out there already in the ecosystem:

   - Here is a recent thread about an official supported [Java client](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/thread/U6U4SMLVVJHISORYJXXPT3BSBE3QHTBW/#VCB6KHV2UWMMNCCJQMK45N54U2JBITDF)
   - Someone in the community has been developing a [node.js client](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/thread/U6U4SMLVVJHISORYJXXPT3BSBE3QHTBW/#VCB6KHV2UWMMNCCJQMK45N54U2JBITDF) for their own purposes (not sure if it's public though)
   - There used to be a Ruby gem but it I believe it is deprecated, but you may be able to find it and look at it for ideas

Comment: actually my endpoint is https://api.run.pivotal.io and I am using that link only in my python script, but it is showing same error.

I heard that first we have to take authentication token, I don't know how to get the token to access. I have only option to use python, that is my actual task

Comment: `api.run.pivotal.io` is still missing a scheme.  You need to add `https`.

Comment: that's became link in above comment, i am using  https only in my code. But the result is same, actually that's the API endpoint.

Comment: Where did you get the `cloudfoundry` module?  You've written `cloudfoundrty` in your code, I assume that's a typo?  Also your error message says `users/kishorekumarnetala%40gmail.com/tokens` but I don't see anything like `kishorekumarnetala@gmail.com` anywhere in your code.  Can you describe exactly where you got the module (so I can try and reproduce the issue), and exactly what code you're running (minus your password), and then exactly what error message you're getting.  I tried `pip install cloudfoundry` but got nothing.

Comment: `pip info python-cloudfoundry` shows that the source comes from https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/python-cloudfoundry which hasn't been updated in 3 years, meaning its APIs are definitely out of date.  `pip search cloudfoundry` shows some other options, which you could call `pip info` on to see if any are more recent/active.

Comment: I have tried `cloudfoundry-client` also but the problem is before get into access cloudfoundry app first authentication token is required. how can i get that. could you send me an working example or try with my credentials

Comment: `cf oauth-token` will display the token.  If you do `CF_TRACE=true cf oauth-token` you can see the HTTP requests/responses that are made by the CLI in order for it to fetch the token, in case you want to replicate the HTTP calls instead of shelling out to the CLI.

Comment: In command prompt all are woking fine. I am getting token also but I want to know how to get that token using my python script and how to manage my apps only by using python script that's my requirement.